# WebView not showing results

Tags: android, webview

If I am typing incorrect query, like this: `dfgkjdfkjg` in address bar I want my WebView to show user a page as Chrome does:
[image]

But it just not loading a url with this query and stays on the home page.

My query looks like this: https://www.google.com/search?q=dfgkjdfkjg.

My code looks like this: `webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/search?q=dfgkjdfkjg")`

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can override onReceivedFunction and load custom page.

```
 @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error){
          // Load custom error page as you want.
    }
```

You should look to the error codes in the below and catch them in the onReceivedError for wrong url.

> WebViewClient.ERROR_AUTHENTICATION
>
> WebViewClient.ERROR_BAD_URL
>
> WebViewClient.ERROR_CONNECT
>
> WebViewClient.ERROR_FAILED_SSL_HANDSHAKE
>
> WebViewClient.ERROR_FILE
>
> WebViewClient.ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
>
> WebViewClient.ERROR_HOST_LOOKUP
>
> WebViewClient.ERROR_IO
>
> WebViewClient.ERROR_PROXY_AUTHENTICATION
>
> WebViewClient.ERROR_REDIRECT_LOOP
>
> WebViewClient.ERROR_TIMEOUT
>
> WebViewClient.ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS
>
> WebViewClient.ERROR_UNKNOWN
>
> WebViewClient.ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_AUTH_SCHEME
>
> WebViewClient.ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_SCHEME

Comment: ok, thank you so much. I will try it tomorrow and tell if it solved my issue.

Comment: So, it didn't help me. In my case this method is not calling. It calls only onPageFinished. But if I type proper query like: `twitter.com` it calls onPageStarted and onPageFinished